# Form validation - Minimum number value

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap

Could someone offer me some advice as to form validation that restricts entry of a number below 5. I have got a donation form, simply an amount input field and a submit button to paypal.

What form validation shall I use to restrict submission of the form if the amount value is below 5 (for £5.00).

The form is below:

```
<form target="paypal" id="donate" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
    <div class="span6 text-center">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="SECRET-ID">
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="General">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="GEN">
        <div class="input-prepend input-append">
            <span class="add-on">£</span>
            <input class="span12" name="amount" value="5" placeholder="Enter Donation Amount" id="appendedPrependedInput" size="20" type="text">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
            <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6 text-center">
        <div class="controls">


    <a id="buynow" class="btn btn-danger" href="#" rel="nofollow" onclick="document.getElementById('donate').submit(); return false;">
        <span style="">Donate via PayPal!</span></a>
    <noscript>
        <style>#buynow { display: none; } #page_theme #donate input { display: inline; }</style>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Donate via PayPal!">
    </noscript>             
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">          
</form>
```

Comment: Why? If it's a donation, why require a minimum?

Comment: Seems like a simple thing. What have you tried or found in the web?

Comment: I don't really want a 1p donation that will cost the charity in paypal fees... @relentless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would use [parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html)

So to use parsley on your form (after you install it), add this data attribute to your form:

```
data-validate="parsley"
```

It should look like this:

```
<form target="paypal" id="donate" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" data-validate="parsley" method="post" >
```

And for your input add the following data attribute (read the documentation for more validation rules):

```
data-min="6"
```

So it should look like:

```
<input class="span12" name="amount" value="5" placeholder="Enter Donation Amount"  data-min="6" id="appendedPrependedInput" size="20" type="text">
```

And that's it.

Comment: That is perfect! I don't code forms much so I am not too experienced with the best validation services! This is being bookmarked right now.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of them, but since most people are already using JQuery and they want to use client-side validations, I would use [Jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). Remember for back-end, you have to use your own PHP, C# or whatever validation that you need. If you aren't using JQuery, I would use [this](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a very simple frontend solution, you can use a Javascript function attached to the onblur event for the input element to test the value of the input:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" onblur="checkValue(this)" />
```

In the attached function, you pass the element and check the value of that element:

```
function checkValue(element){
    if(element.value < 5){
        alert('The minimum donation is 5.00!');
        // clear value, display message, etc.
    }
}
```

This function will be triggered whenever the cursor leaves the input field. A simple alert may be all you need. You may also want to add additional check to make sure the element input is actually a number and not a string. It's best to assume the end-user will not know how to use the form.

Please note that this is only a frontend solution and all submitted forms should be validated on the server-side language of choice (e.g. PHP). You should not accept this Javascript validation as a reliable validator when saving data.